# Index pages for previous months?

Tags: google-index

Is there a way on how to find number of index pages for last 2-3 months. If yes, then how??
Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your question to indicate that you are looking for back-links within a specified period as you've mentioned in your comments.

You can use the link operator on Google to find back links (for example - link:mvark.blogspot.com will show back-links for my blog). In the side bar on Google Search, click on "More Search Tools" & then pick "Past month" or specify Custom Range from the list under the section "Any Time" to see back-links during a specified period.

[You can also Google Webmaster Tools to analyze back-links](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/google-provides-backlink-tool-for-site-owners/)

Answer (score 0):

The beste way to find out all information about how Google sees your website, how its crawled, indexed etcetera is by using Google Webmaster tools: www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Comment: Hey BasP, thanks for the reply. However, I am aware about these things. I was actually looking out for a way wherein I can find out the number of back-links for previous months. For e.g. the current month is March-2011, how can I find out the back-links for Jan-2011? Is there any way to find it out?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely look at Google Webmaster Tools as this will tell you all about your site and how it is indexed. You will be able to see backlinks to your site and how your site appears to Google.

One other interesting way to keep tabs on your indexed pages is using a Google Alert. This won't be able to help you with past pages, but is a way to see new pages as they get indexed. Set up a Google alert for the search:

> site:www.yourdomain.com

You will get an email each time a new page on your site is indexed.

Comment: Hey lovefaithswing, thanks for the reply. However, I am aware about these things. I was actually looking out for a way wherein I can find out the number of back-links for previous months. For e.g. the current month is March-2011, how can I find out the back-links for Jan-2011? Is there any way to find it out?

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest Ahrefs.com as one best tool if you want to check past 2-3 months backlink report.

This tool is one of the awesome link research tool. It provides some link research and link analysis features to paid users but some basic tools on this site are free for webmasters.

This tool provides fresh data all the time as the index refreshes itself every half hour. This tool provides link research options including the following features:

site explorer (Overview, External backlinks, New backlinks, Lost backlinks, Anchors,   Crawled pages, Referring domains, Raw data export)

SERPs Analysis (Position Analysis, Daily Stats, Daily Stats table, History of changes, Ads Analysis),  Reports (Report list, Own domain, Standard report, Report filters, Raw Export report)

Labs (Ahrefs Top, Domain Comparison, Chart Comparison, Batch Analysis).